# java listening port os x

Tags: java, macos, tcp

I've written a simple java program that creates a ServerSocket and returns some html. The program seems to work properly, but I can only get a response from using a browser on the localhost and not external devices.

Only when my mac (OS X 10.10; Yosemite) goes to sleep and then wakes up is when external devices will be able to get something from the java application.

Before putting the laptop to sleep and after starting the java program,  I've run 'sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP', and I see that it was listening to the port on which I instantiated my ServerSocket.

```
java      6539      hostname    7u  IPv6 0xf465ab9093077243      0t0    TCP *:4444 (LISTEN).
```

and it remains pretty much the same when I've rerun the command again after waking it from sleep.

I'm wondering what's going on here, and how can i just have external devices connect to my java program work when I start it, without putting my laptop to sleep first.

**Update 1:**
The code works fine on localhost.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Start!");
    ServerSocket listener = null;
    try {
        listener = new ServerSocket(4444, 1, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {0,0,0,0}));
        System.out.println("listening");
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("listening...");

            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            System.out.println("connection accepted");
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                out.println("\r\n");
                out.println(new Date().toString());
                out.println("<h1>hello world</h1>");
                out.println("this is only a test!");
                out.println(""+ socket.getPort());
                System.out.println("connection at port "+socket.toString());//socket.getPort());
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } finally {

                System.out.println("close socket");
                socket.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Loop End");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if (listener != null)
        try {
            listener.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("End!");
```

Comment: Without your code no one can help you.

Comment: "I can only get a response from using a browser on the localhost and not external devices" specifically what happens when an external device tries to access the service?

Comment: The web client eventually just times out.